# How to write single statement to retrieve last resume of user watching video if the complete date less than resume date?

Tags: mysql

I am sure this is pretty simple to do but I can’t do that. My problem :
I Have my sql database with one table keeping users video watching complete status(1) and resume(0). once the user is completed she/he again can watch the video the entry will be resume mode then status again insert 0 to this table.

TableName : sdbi_splms_videohit_track

```
       Id    videoid   status  userid  watch_date
```

---

```
       1     912230      0        1      2020-08-31 15:54:14              
       2     912230      1        1      2020-09-09 15:54:14
```

We need to retrieve only resume videos records the is status =0 and if the is status =1 and  watch_date grater resume status=0.

### Then First out put

it`s should retrieve 0  record because watch_date date greater that resume status

```
            ------ Watching this  again on entry increase------------      
              Id    videoid   status  userid  watch_date           
              1     912230      0          1      2020-08-031 15:54:14              
              2     912230      1          1      2020-09-09 15:54:14   
              3     912230      0          1      2020-09-10 15:54:14
```

Out put the last one if resume again

```
              3     912230      0              1      2020-09-10 15:54:14
```

My sql current query is below its always return resume record if completed date is greater resume date :

```
             SELECT a.* FROM `sdbi_splms_videohit_track` as a WHERE a.videoid=912230 AND 
            `a`.`user_view_video` = '0' AND `a`.`user_id` = '1'  GROUP BY b.videoid ORDER BY 
             MAX(a.date_created) DESC
```

Can you please guide me , if it is possible in single query.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It's not clear how the resume status (boolean or integer) can compare to watch_date (datetime). I seams to me that  you may want to rethink your database and at least set two  datetime fields, pickupt_date(your watch_date) and return_date.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to help you with the information you are providing. Maybe you want to consider some changes in you database using at least three tables Like:

```
users_table
user_id int primary key autoincrement
user_name varchar(xxx)
...........
user_attribute(n)

videos_table
video_id int primary key autoincrement
video_name varchar(xxx)
...........
video_attribute(n)

video_track
id int primary_key autoincrement
video_id int
user_id int
pickup_date date
return_date date default null
```

This would allow you to select the videos taken from a user and not returned yet (your status 0) like.

```
SELECT vt.video_id, vt.video_name 
FROM videos_track k
INNER JOIN users_table ut using (user_id) 
INNER JOIN video_table vt using (video_id)
WHERE ISNULL(k.return_date)
AND ut.user_id = 1
```

So this query will give you all videos picked up by the user with user:id = 1 and yet not returned. If you need the videos picked up after certain date, you add this condition to the WHERE clause:

```
AND k.pickup_date <= limit_date
```

etc.
In other words, You'll be able to query your data with a variety of different questions.
Hope I got the essence of your issue so it may be af any help.